# How to make JFrame or JPanel Scrollable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

i have added multiple component on JPanel & then i add JPanel on JFrame.

how to make window scrollable ?

so i can add more component at that frame or window .

Comment: There's a nice scroll pane tutorial on the swing site: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Answer (score 10):

Before adding your `JPanel`, put in a `JScrollPane` first:

```
JPanel panel = ...;
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
frame.add(scroll, ...);
```

Comment: Don't you have to do frame.add(scroll, ...)? I mean you have to add the JScrollPane, not the JPanel directly right?

Comment: `Beat you by 11 seconds. :) (Plus I was able to provide a code sample as well)` - yes but your code example was wrong. Your description is still confusing. It still sounds like you add the panel to the frame.

Comment: @camickr You are just pointing out what Trust noticed 50 minutes ago, which has already been resolved. You appear to be kind of late.

Comment: This code does not work if you have a null layout on your panel.

Answer (score 3):

Just putting your JPanel in a JScrollPane and adding this to the JFrame should do the trick....

Comment: Beat you by 11 seconds. :) (Plus I was able to provide a code sample as well)

Comment: i tried following code but not working yet: 
      JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(mainpanel);
      mainframe.add(jsp);